# Reading .csv using fread works on OSX not on Windows

Tags: r, csv, operating-system, data.table, fread

I have an annoying csv > 10gb which opens on Mac OSX but not on Windows 10.

The code I use

```
data_in <- fread("my_data.csv")
```

SessionInfo Windows

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.10.4-3 forcats_0.3.0       stringr_1.3.0       dplyr_0.7.4         purrr_0.2.4         readr_1.1.1         tidyr_0.8.0         tibble_1.4.2       
 [9] ggplot2_2.2.1       tidyverse_1.2.1     RMySQL_0.10.14      DBI_0.8            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.2.1     compiler_3.4.4   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1      tools_3.4.4      lubridate_1.7.2  jsonlite_1.5    
[10] nlme_3.1-131.1   gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.0      psych_1.8.3.3    cli_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.7   yaml_2.1.18     
[19] parallel_3.4.4   haven_1.1.1      bindrcpp_0.2.2   xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       hms_0.4.2        grid_3.4.4       glue_1.2.0       R6_2.2.2        
[28] readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-69   modelr_0.1.1     reshape2_1.4.3   magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5    
[37] colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.7    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.4      crayon_1.3.4
```

SessionInfo OSX

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8/C/sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.19
```

The error I get on Windows, I have tried all suggested solutions found without any luck.

> Expecting 10 cols, but line 1346596 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.
>   In addition: Warning message:

Additional info when using `verbose = TRUE` (Windows) (Tried a smaller file, same problem)

```
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.004474 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Positioned on line 1 after skip or autostart
This line is the autostart and not blank so searching up for the last non-blank ... line 1
Detecting sep ... ','
Detected 10 columns. Longest stretch was from line 1 to line 30
Starting data input on line 1 (either column names or first row of data). First 10 characters: ,asin,sale
All the fields on line 1 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
Count of eol: 3657 (including 0 at the end)
Count of sep: 138915
nrow = MIN( nsep [138915] / (ncol [10] -1), neol [3657] - endblanks [0] ) = 3657
Type codes (point  0): 1444444340
Type codes (point  1): 1444444340
Type codes (point  2): 1444444340
Type codes (point  3): 1444444340
Type codes (point  4): 1444444344
Type codes (point  5): 1444444344
Type codes (point  6): 1444444344
Type codes (point  7): 1444444344
Type codes (point  8): 1444444344
Type codes (point  9): 1444444344
Type codes (point 10): 1444444444
Type codes: 1444444444 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 1444444444 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 10 column slots (10 - 0 dropped)
Error in fread("md2.csv", verbose = T) : 
  Expecting 10 cols, but line 3312 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.
```

`verbose = T` OSX

```
nput contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
[01] Check arguments
  Using 4 threads (omp_get_max_threads()=4, nth=4)
  NAstrings = [<<NA>>]
  None of the NAstrings look like numbers.
  show progress = 1
  0/1 column will be read as integer
[02] Opening the file
  Opening file md2.csv
  File opened, size = 4.581MB (4803885 bytes).
  Memory mapped ok
[03] Detect and skip BOM
[04] Arrange mmap to be \0 terminated
  \n has been found in the input and different lines can end with different line endings (e.g. mixed \n and \r\n in one file). This is common and ideal.
  File ends abruptly with ','. Final end-of-line is missing. Using cow page to write 0 to the last byte.
[05] Skipping initial rows if needed
  Positioned on line 1 starting: <<,asin,salesRank,imUrl,categori>>
[06] Detect separator, quoting rule, and ncolumns
  Detecting sep automatically ...
  sep=','  with 100 lines of 10 fields using quote rule 0
  Detected 10 columns on line 1. This line is either column names or first data row. Line starts as: <<,asin,salesRank,imUrl,categori>>
  Quote rule picked = 0
  fill=false and the most number of columns found is 10
[07] Detect column types, good nrow estimate and whether first row is column names
  Number of sampling jump points = 10 because (4803885 bytes from row 1 to eof) / (2 * 127664 jump0size) == 18
  Type codes (jump 000)    : 5AAAAAA7A2  Quote rule 0
  Type codes (jump 004)    : 5AAAAAA7AA  Quote rule 0
  Type codes (jump 010)    : 5AAAAAA7AA  Quote rule 0
  'header' determined to be true due to column 8 containing a string on row 1 and a lower type (float64) in the rest of the 1041 sample rows
  =====
  Sampled 1041 rows (handled \n inside quoted fields) at 11 jump points
  Bytes from first data row on line 2 to the end of last row: 4803813
  Line length: mean=2028.07 sd=3025.66 min=28 max=29901
  Estimated number of rows: 4803813 / 2028.07 = 2369
  Initial alloc = 4738 rows (2369 + 100%) using bytes/max(mean-2*sd,min) clamped between [1.1*estn, 2.0*estn]
  =====
[08] Assign column names
[09] Apply user overrides on column types
  After 0 type and 0 drop user overrides : 5AAAAAA7AA
[10] Allocate memory for the datatable
  Allocating 10 column slots (10 - 0 dropped) with 4738 rows
[11] Read the data
  jumps=[0..2), chunk_size=2401906, total_size=4803813
Read 3311 rows x 10 columns from 4.581MB (4803885 bytes) file in 00:00.025 wall clock time
[12] Finalizing the datatable
  Type counts:
         1 : int32     '5'
         1 : float64   '7'
         8 : string    'A'
=============================
   0.001s (  2%) Memory map 0.004GB file
   0.005s ( 19%) sep=',' ncol=10 and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection using 1041 sample rows
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation of 4738 rows x 10 cols (0.000GB) of which 3311 ( 70%) rows used
   0.019s ( 78%) Reading 2 chunks (0 swept) of 2.291MB (each chunk 1655 rows) using 2 threads
   +    0.004s ( 15%) Parse to row-major thread buffers (grown 0 times)
   +    0.012s ( 48%) Transpose
   +    0.004s ( 15%) Waiting
   0.000s (  0%) Rereading 0 columns due to out-of-sample type exceptions
   0.025s        Total
```

Comment: This is a massive file, and FYI, R operates completely in memory.  Is there any chance that your Windows simply does not have enough free RAM to handle loading the entire file?

Comment: Can you read it in, in chunks?

Comment: could you include the package version of data.table? also try running fread with verbose=TRUE for extra debugging clues

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I added some info to my original questions. Adam, RAM is not a issue (32gb).

Comment: what's the verbose info on Mac?

Comment: also, I still don't see the package versions. given that the R version is different, I worry the data.table version differs as well

Comment: @MichaelChirico tried updating to the newest version, no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in newest version of `data.table`

Comment: you could add some more detail about how you solved your problem -- it would make this more useful to future readers who may be faced with a similar situation :)